# generating a hash lookup table for indexes of objects in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create a lookup table to find the index of an object in an array:

Eet an array `["a", "b", "c"]` and generate a lookup hash table for each object's indexes `{"a"=>0, "b"=>1, "c"=>2}`

The simplest ways I can come up with are:

```
i = 0
lookup = array.each_with_object({}) do |value,hash|
  hash[value] = i
  i += 1
end
```

and:

```
i = -1
lookup = Hash[array.map {|x| [x, i+=1]}]
```

I feel there are more elegant solutions to doing this, any idea is welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
Hash[array.zip 0..array.length]
```

Comment: just did the benchmark (code in my answer), your idea is even faster

Answer (score 2):

```
lookup  = Hash[array.each_with_index.map{|el,i| [el, i]}]
```

---

@Mark Thomas answer is even faster than mine:

```
array = (0..100000).to_a;
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { Hash[array.each_with_index.map{|el,i| [el, i]}] }
  x.report { Hash[array.zip 0..array.length] }
end

     user     system      total        real
 0.050000   0.010000   0.060000 (  0.053233)
 0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.036471)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the benchmarks!

Your answer is interesting though, i've never seen each_with_index and map chained like that. Can you elaborate on how it works?

Comment: On my machine, with the exact same benchmark code, your code constantly runs faster than Mark Thomas's.

Comment: @randomtaiwanese: `each_with_index` gives you an enumerator, poiting to each element of the array + it's index. When you use `map` you simply retrieve the enum values and build your array. Clearer?

Answer (score 2):

Slightly slower than apneadiving's code, but simpler:

```
 Hash[array.map.with_index.to_a]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
lookup = {}
arr.each_with_index { |elem,index|  lookup[elem] = index }
```